# In react material ui expansion panel allow expand collapse on specfic text

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

On [Expansion Panel](https://material-ui.com/api/expansion-panel/) I want the expansion or collapse should happen in a specific area.

[image]
Rather I want to know how we can manually expand or collapse the expansion panel.

Expansion panel codesandbox link 
https://codesandbox.io/s/64187n5o9k

Comment: you should just send the prop `expanded` to it, no? Currently I have a hard time understanding what you would like to do though, is it limiting it to a certain area (therefor disabling default behavior), or manually triggering it? Your code looks pretty straightforward to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove the `onChange` event on ExpansionPanel.

`<ExpansionPanel expanded={expanded === "panel1"}>`

Then you would need to use a click event on the area you want to use to expand

```
<ExpansionPanelSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}>
    <Typography className={classes.heading}>
        General settings
    </Typography>
    <button type="button" onClick={this.handleChange("panel1")}>
        I am an expansion panel
    </button>
</ExpansionPanelSummary>
```

Click event example:

```
handleChange = panel => () => {
    this.setState({
        expanded: this.state.expanded !== panel ? panel : ""
    });
};
```